# Is there any mantra that addresses the Saptarishi?

Tags: mantras, rishi, vedic-rituals, saptarshi

Is there a mantra that addresses all of the Saptarishi. I used to chant "Om Jai Shri Saptarishi Namah". I found out that "Chitrasikhandin" is a word used to refer to the seven sages, so I made up another mantra: Om Jai Shri Chitrasikhandin Namah. Are there anything similar in the texts?

I feel that we Hindus today do not give enough respect and praise to the Saptarishi.

Comment: haha you made up the mantra? i made up this Om saptarishibhyo namaha.

Comment: @Rickross My knowledge of Sanskrit is very limited and I probably should not be making up mantras. Thanks for sharing your mantra. I just learned that "bhyo" makes it plural. :) So, can "Om Chitrasikhandinbhyo Namaha" work?

Comment: Yes Bhyo is for plural, for eg- Navagrahebhyo (9 planetary deities), Sarva Devebhyo (all the deities), Sarva Rishibyo (all the rishis) etc. I am not aware of Chitrasinkandin. Anyways i look for specialized mantras for the Sapta Rishis.

Answer (score 3):

mantras there are many praises in rig-veda a hymn i got in rig-veda is a hymn to sage vashistha i f you see vedas you will find a lot of praises but the term saptrishi is not used in vedas. but in brahmanas aranyakas etc.
only 5 verses i am giving here:—

> **HYMN XXXIII Vasiṣṭha.**
>
> 1. THESE who wear hair-knots on the
>      right, the movers of holy thought,
>      white-robed, have won me over.
>      I warned the men, when from the
>      grass I raised me, Not from afar can
>      my Vasisthas help you.
>
> 2 With Soma they brought Indra
>   from a distance, Over Vaisanta, from
>   the strong libation.
>   Indra preferred Vasisthas to the
>   Soma pressed by the son of Vayata,
>   Pasadyumna.
>
> 3 So, verily, with these he crossed
>   the river, in company with these he
>   slaughtered Bheda.
>   So in the fight with the Ten Kings,
>   Vasisthas! did Indra help Sudās
>   through your devotions.
>
> 4 I gladly, men I with prayer prayed
>   by our fathers have fixed your axle:
>   ye shall not be injured:
>   Since, when ye sang aloud the
>   Sakvari verses, Vasisthas! ye
>   invigorated Indra.
>
> 5 Like thirsty men they looked to
>   heaven, in battle with the Ten Kings,
>   surrounded and imploring.
>   Then Indra heard Vasiṣṭha as he
>   praised him, and gave the Trtsus
>   ample room and freedom.
>
> source: http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv07033.htm

Brihadaranyaka Upanishad(2.2.4)
acknowledge the names of seven
rishis(or Saptarshis)

> 2.2.3 Regarding
>   this there is the
>   following verse:
>   There is a bowl that has its opening below and bulges at the top; various kinds of knowledge have been put in it; seven sages sit by its side, and the organ of speech, which has communication with the Vedas, is the eighth'. The 'bowl that has its opening below and bulges at the top' is this head of ours, for it is the bowl that has its opening below and bulges at the top.'Various kinds of knowledge have been put in it', refers to the organs; these indeed represent various kinds of knowledge. 'Seven sages sit by its side', refers to the organs; they indeed are the sages. 'The organ of speech, which has communication with the Vedas, is the eighth', because the organ of speech is the eighth and communicates with the Vedas.
>
> **2.2.4 These two
>   (ears) are Gotama
>   and Bharadvaja:
>   this one is
>   Gotama, and this
>   one Bharadvaja:
>   These two (eyes)
>   are Visvamitra and
>   Jamadagni: this
>   one is Visvamitra,
>   and this one
>   Jamadagni. These
>   two (nostrils) are
>   Vasistha, and
>   Kasyapa: this one
>   is Vasistha, and
>   this one Kasyapa:
>   The tongue is Atri,
>   for through the
>   tongue food is
>   eaten. 'Atri' is but
>   this name 'Atti'.
>   He who knows it
>   as such becomes
>   the eater of all,
>   and everything
>   becomes his food.**

Comment: I'm aware of mantras to each of the individual Saptarishi, I just want mantras that praises them all together. For example, "Om Saptarishibhyo Namaha" is one mantra that praises all of them at once.

Comment: @Maha Rex i got a mantra to saptarishi but it doesnt't have a sourse if you want i can give you the mantra and link to the page. ;)

Comment: Yes, please. I'll take a look at it.

Comment: @Maha Rex ok if you want it friend this is it:—

कश्यपोत्रिर्भरद्वाजो विश्वामित्रोथ
गौतमः।
जमदग्निर्वसिष्ठश्च सप्तैते ऋषयः
स्मृताः॥
दहन्तु पापं सर्व गृह्नन्त्वर्ध्यं नमो
नमः'॥


link:— http://m.hindi.webdunia.com/astrology-tantra-mantra-yantra/saptarishi-mantra-117082500056_1.html

although it doesn't have a scriptual refrence then also i hope it helps.;)

Comment: @Maha Rex no problem.;)